# Trying to take data from form and insert into database using PDO

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I am trying to submit data from a form and have the data be inserted into my database using PDO. I am unsure what i am doing wrong at this point and could use any help that i can get.

Here is the code for connecting to my db

```
<?php
function connect(){
    $config = array(
      '$username' => 'root',
      '$password' => 'root'
    );
    try {
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', $config['$username'], $config['$password']);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      echo 'COME GET SOME IT WORKED!!!!';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      print "Error!";
      exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the code for handling the form data

```
<?php
 // We will include connection file first
 include('functions.php');
 connect();
 // check if varaibable is set and Add Rate Button pressed.
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   echo 'COME GET SOME';
   // Define Variables
   $firstname = $_POST[firstName]; //firstName
   $lastname = $_POST[lastName]; //LastName
   $email = $_POST[emailAddress]; //Email Address
   $age = $_POST[age]; //Age

   // We Will prepare SQL Query
   $STM = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO 'EmailList'(id, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age) VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :age)");
   // bind paramenters, Named parameters always start with colon(:)
      $STM->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
      $STM->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
      $STM->bindParam(':email', $email);
      $STM->bindParam(':age', $age);
   // For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
      $STM->execute();
   // We use header here for redirecting it to other page where we will show success message.                       
      header( "location:index.php");                   
   }
?>
```

Comment: What had gone wrong?

Comment: Your connection is in a function, and is not in scope. Change the `echo 'COME GET SOME IT WORKED!!!!';` to `return $conn;` in your `function connect()` and then in your code change `connect();` to `$dbh = connect();`

Comment: `INSERT INTO 'EmailList'` remove the quotes.